# saveAsTable ends in failure in Spark-yarn cluster environment

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I set up a spark-yarn cluster environment, and try spark-SQL with spark-shell:

```
spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf spark.yarn.archive=hdfs://hadoop_273_namenode_ip:namenode_port/spark-archive.zip
```

One thing to mention is the Spark is in Windows 7. After spark-shell starts up successfully, I execute the commands as below:

```
scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
scala> val df_mysql_address = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://mysql_db_ip/db").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "ADDRESS").option("user", "root").option("password", "root").load()
scala> df_mysql_address.show
scala> df_mysql_address.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable("address_local")
```

"show" command returns result-set correctly, but the "saveAsTable" ends in failure. The error message says:

```
java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/C:/jshen.workspace/programs/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-warehouse/address_local/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20171018104423_0001_m_000000_0 (exists=false, cwd=file:/tmp/hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1508319604173_0005/container_1508319604173_0005_01_000003)
```

I expect and guess the table is to be saved in the hadoop cluster, but you can see that the dir (C:/jshen.workspace/programs/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-warehouse) is the folder in my Windows 7, not in hdfs, not even in the hadoop ubuntu machine.

How could I do? Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Did you try providing the absolute path of your HDFS to saveAsTable? Like `saveAsTable("hdfs://nn1/user/cloudera/address_local") `

Comment: Thanks @philantrovert, inspired by your proposal. I worked out the right way to get it, that is to provide _"path"_ option prior to _"save"_ operation:   
_scala> df_mysql_address.write..option("path", "/spark-warehouse").format("parquet").saveAsTable("address_local")_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get rid of the problem is to provide "path" option prior to "save" operation as shown below:

```
scala> df_mysql_address.write.option("path", "/spark-warehouse").format("parquet").saveAsTable("address_l‌​ocal")
```

Thanks @philantrovert.